# How to get selected chips from ChipView?

Tags: java, android, android-chips

I am using android [ChipView library](https://github.com/jakebonk/ChipView)
 .I didn't found any doc regarding this.

Please refer to this

`compile 'com.github.jakebonk:ChipView:1.0.1'`

I went through the code but there is no method that return selected tag from the list. Is there any way out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a list / reference to the items as they are added to the adapter. This is something I created for a similar library:

```
    participantsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Timber.d("Item clicked position is: " +position);
            ParticipantChipInput selectedChip =
                    participantChipListAdapter.getParticipantChipInputs().get(position);

            selectedChip.setSelected(!selectedChip.isSelected());

            if (selectedChip.isSelected()) {
                participantChipsList.addChip(selectedChip);
            } else {
                participantChipsList.removeChip(selectedChip);
            }
            participantChipListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `participantsListView` where would I get this list? There is already a listview inside the library with no public method to access data.